# Laravel 5.5 cant find the page

Tags: laravel

recently i'm facing strange issue with my app which wasn't exist at least until yesterday!

If I try to open certain urls such as `myapp.dev/blog` or `myapp.dev/categories` etc. I get error of

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

but if I change my url to something like `myapp.dev/t/blog` it will load the page!

any idea?

## Update

```
Route::get('/categories', 'frontend\FrontendController@totalcategories')->name('allcategories')->where('slug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
```

Comment: Can you please show your web.php file?

Comment: @GautamPatadiya updated

Comment: try to move your at end of file or start of file in web.php. In my case sometime it's behave if while your url getting conflict with each other.

Comment: @GautamPatadiya working now, but what if again this happen? is there any permanent solution for it? i mean can't move routes every time this happen, specially when site is live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to move your at end of file or start of file in web.php. In my case sometime it's behave if while your url getting conflict with each other.

in my case my was like routes this

```
Route::get('{status}/category','TempController@index');
Route::get('category/t','TempController@store');
```

Simply I just moved myfirst line at end of file. and worked fine.

This happend because Laravel treat first Segment of URL as argument.