# laravel 5 slug will not return pages

Tags: php, laravel, slug

I try to get my route without any additional parameter in url and i'm getting `Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.` error.

If I use url like: `domain/category/lenovo` where lenovo is my slug it's working. But if I try to get my url like: `domain/lenovo` I'm gettin error above.

here is my codes:

`route`

```
Route::get('/{categoryslug}', 'frontend\FrontendController@totalcategoriessubs')->name('catwithsubs')->where('categoryslug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
```

`function`

```
public function totalcategoriessubs($categoryslug) {
    $categories = Category::where('slug','=',$categoryslug)->with('subcategories')->paginate(12);
    return view('front.categoriessubs', compact('categories'));
  }
```

it also brakes my other urls such as `domain/admin/dashboard` etc.

any idea?

Comment: Does your route have any prefix assigned to it?

Comment: @linktoahref admin part yes, but the rest such as`domain/category/lenovo` no

Comment: please add your full routes file

Comment: may be this can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48124579/laravel-5-5-cant-find-the-page/48124820#48124820

Comment: @GautamPatadiya the purpose is to remove that additional part not to move it in other place, have you seen urls of `wordpress` `joomla` `magento` etc. ?

Comment: @Sohel0415 I don't think if that's necessary bro, my issue is in that line of code which i shared already.

Comment: @mafortis may be its not, as what you have shown is perfectly alright, may be problem lies elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

It seems that is caused by the order of your routes.

Your actual problem is that when you hit a fixed endpoint, for example `/dashboard` this will be handled by `Route::get('/{categoryslug}', ...)` before the correct endpoint (`Route::get('dashboard', ...)`). So, as your system notices that there is no category with that slug (`dashboard`) it throws the error.

Try change the order of your routes, like this:

```php
Route::get('/category/{categorySlug}', 'CategoryController@index');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@home');
// and so on..

Route::get('/{categoryslug}', 'frontend\FrontendController@totalcategoriessubs')
        ->name('catwithsubs')->where('categoryslug', '[\w\d\-\_]+');
```

Always put the routes that have fixed parts (`.../category/...`)of the route before the ones that have dynamic elements (`.../{categoryslug}/`).